RPG main site—and only RPG main—in read-only mode for me?
I can access other Stack Exchange sites, and I can access here, obviously, and I can see other people active on RPG main, but for me, RPG is read-only, with links to Stack Status (which shows no problems) and a search of Meta’s maintenance or site-maintenance tags (last activity from May).
Is anyone else experiencing this? Why on earth am I experiencing it? How can I make it stop?

This has been going on for a lot longer than the 7 minutes since that top question was modified in the screenshot.

Not read-only for me presently.

Try clearing your browser cookies.
Similar reports on meta.se:

Math stackexchange in "Read-only mode" for me but I see other people posting, and status page shows operational
Stack Overflow in Read Only mode for past 2 days

A few users suggest that clearing cookies from your browser may resolve the issue.

In the end, it went away on its own, so I can’t personally confirm what you found, but that certainly does look like the answer. Thanks!

I did not experience that yet, but I got weird 404 Not Found error messages repeatedly when posting an answer. Reloading the page fixed it. Using Chrome. And I get a 404 Not Found on the first of the two links above, too.

@NobodytheHobgoblin See this bug report for your issue
